# On the Kolmogorov consistency theorem

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

This theorem says that for any reasonable (i.e., *consistent*) family of finite-dimensional distributions, there exists one and only one stochastic process with these distributions.
Being *consistent* means satisfying certain conditions. Here's one of them:

> Let $T$ denote some interval (thought of as "time"), and let $n\in \mathbb {N}$. For each $k\in \mathbb {N}$ and finite sequence of distinct times $t_{1},\dots ,t_{k}\in T$, let $\nu _{t_{1}\dots t_{k}}$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb {R} ^{n})^{k}$.
> Then for all permutations $\pi$  of $\{1,\dots ,k\}$ and measurable sets $F_{i}\subseteq \mathbb {R} ^{n}$,
> $$\nu _{t_{\pi (1)}\dots t_{\pi (k)}}\left(F_{\pi (1)}\times \dots \times F_{\pi (k)}\right)=\nu _{t_{1}\dots t_{k}}\left(F_{1}\times \dots \times F_{k}\right)$$

Simply put, if I understood it correctly, this condition says the joint probability of finding $X=x_1$ at $T=t_1$ and $X=x_2$ at $T=t_2$ doesn't care about the chronological order.

But... **how can this be true for any stochastic process**? Its time evolution might make the probability of finding certain values later higher than early, so there's not invariance under permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting that condition on $\nu$. The theorem says that if you have a family $\nu_{t_1, \dots, t_n}$ satisfying the consistency conditions then there is a process such that
$$\nu_{t_1, \dots, t_n} (F_1 \times \dots F_n) = \mathbb{P}(X_{t_1} \in F_1, \dots, X_{t_n} \in F_n).$$

Written in terms of the process, the permutation condition then says that
$$\mathbb{P}(X_{t_1} \in F_1, \dots, X_{t_n} \in F_n) = \mathbb{P}(X_{t_{\pi(1)}} \in F_{\pi(1)}, \dots, X_{t_{\pi(n)}} \in F_{\pi(n)})$$
which is trivially true for any stochastic process since it just amounts to writing the conditions $X_{t_i} \in F_{i}$ in a different order on the right hand side. That is, the order in which the $t_i$ appear in time doesn't change, only the order in which I write down the resulting conditions.

Comment: But isn't this true always? Why is it even a condition?

Comment: Consider the case where space is one-dimensional and define $\nu_{s,t} = \delta_{(1,1)}$ if $s > t$ and $\nu_{s,t} = \delta_{(-1,-1)}$ if $s < t$. Then $\nu_{2,1}(\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}_+) = 1$ and $\nu_{1,2}(\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}_+) = 0$. That is, this is an example where the permutation condition fails.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please put it in terms of probability? I haven't a strong enough background in measure theory

Comment: You will have to be comfortable with what a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is to understand the theorem and that should be all you need to understand my last comment. If you are asking me to write the last comment in terms of the probability a process takes values in some sets then I think you have misunderstood the theorem since at the start you don't have such a process so you can't write the assumptions in terms of them. You check the assumptions and then you get the process (and the existence of the process does imply the assumptions are true but you had to know that already anyway)